# Bbugs out when execution

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

I couldn't find out what the problem with this code was after 3 hours of seaching on google.
The code stops working when `ExecuteNonQuery` runs. Then I get a timeout.
I don't have any problem to list from the database but deleting is.

```vb
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=" & Me.txt_mysqlHost.Text & "; user id=" & Me.txt_mysqlUser.Text & "; password=" & Me.txt_mysqlPassword.Text & "; database=" & Me.txt_mysqlDatabase.Text)
con.Open()
Dim mySelectQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Lager WHERE Artikelnr = '" & Artikelnr & "'"
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, con)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: did it return any error message?

Comment: @JW. he facing the _timeout_ server `:D`